# Different attribute values for each attribute set in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I have few attribute sets (for e.g. Men shoes, men clothes) and each of them have same attributes (like size, color), but every attribute have different scope of values for each set. 
Is it possible to split values of attribute by attribute sets?

P.S. i'm using Magento CE 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

No need of adding different attribute of size and color for Men Shoes and Men Clothes.You can add only 1 attribute for size and 1 for color from admin and assign all the values of two sets in same attribute.
The value you will select from admin for a particular product accordingly it will show in frontend.